# Stack alignment in x64 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, memory-alignment, calling-convention, stack-pointer

how is the value of `28h` (decimal 40) that is subtracted from `rsp` calculated in the following:

```
    option casemap:none

    includelib kernel32.lib
    includelib user32.lib

externdef MessageBoxA : near
externdef ExitProcess : near

    .data

text    db 'Hello world!', 0
caption db 'Hello x86-64', 0

    .code

main proc
    sub rsp, 28h        ; space for 4 arguments + 16byte aligned stack
    xor r9d, r9d        ; 4. argument: r9d = uType = 0
    lea r8, [caption]   ; 3. argument: r8  = caption
    lea rdx, [text]     ; 2. argument: edx = window text
    xor rcx, rcx        ; 1. argument: rcx = hWnd = NULL
    call MessageBoxA
    xor ecx, ecx        ; ecx = exit code
    call ExitProcess
main endp

    end
```

from: http://www.japheth.de/JWasm/Win64_1.html

By my understanding I would have to only subtract `20h` since each value I'm using takes 8 bytes into 4 is `20h`. so why is `28h` being subtracted and how does that result in 16 byte alignment?

see also [Is reserving stack space necessary for functions less than four arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392344/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe it's because before `main` is called, the stack is aligned. Then after the `call`, the act of the `call` was to push an 8-byte pointer (the address within the caller to return to, which is the address right after the call instruction) onto the stack. So at the beginning of `main`, it's 8 bytes off of the 16-byte alignment. Therefore, instead of `20h` you need `28h`, bringing the actual total to `28h + 8h` (from the `call`) or `30h`. Alignment. :)

Comment: Maybe it should be (*return* address *in* the caller).

Comment: @smwikipedia thanks, good clarification. I updated with some similar wording.

Answer (score 1):

I had stumbled upon the same case. Tried lurker answer and was fine. Later added some code(by the way, i'm using my own compiler) and got problems.

The problem was that the shadow space address was ending with 8 on the stack. When the shadow space address was ending with 0 ("Stack aligned on 16 bytes"), the call was OK.
Adding 8 bytes will crash the app in my last case.